# Backbone not evaluates url function before request

Tags: ajax, rest, backbone.js

I'm trying to use Backbone with REST API:

Here the code

My model:

```
var PagesModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: 'Guid',
    initialize: function () {
        this.on('remove', this.destroy);
    },
    urlRoot: '/api/pages'
});
```

Collection:

```
var PagesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: PagesModel,
        url: '/api/pages'
    });
```

View:

```
var PagesView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#pages',
    events: {
        'click .removePage': 'remove',
    },
    initialize: function (collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.template = $('#pages-template').html();
        this.collection.bind('change reset', this.render, this);

    },
    render: function () {
        var template = _.template(this.template);
        $(this.el).html(template({ pages: this.collection.toJSON() }));
        return this;
    },
    remove: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(e.currentTarget).closest('ul').data("id");
        var item = this.collection.get(id);
        this.collection.remove(item);
        $(e.currentTarget).closest('ul').fadeOut(300, function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }
});
```

And here I'm starting up application:

```
$(function () {
    var pagesCollection = new PagesCollection();
    var pagesView = new PagesView(pagesCollection);
});
```

I'm clicking or Remove and in Network inspector see this link

```
http://localhost:54286/backbone/function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20base%20=%20getValue(this,%20'urlRoot')%20%7C%7C%20getValue(this.collection,%20'url')%20%7C%7C%20urlError();%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.isNew())%20return%20base;%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20base%20+%20(base.charAt(base.length%20-%201)%20==%20'/'%20?%20''%20:%20'/')%20+%20encodeURIComponent(this.id);%20%20%20%20}
```

instead of /api/pages/{guid}.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think there's a part of your code is missing. Have you tried using routes?

Comment: Here the minimal working sample. Routes are not connected with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still haven't figured fully why, but you can make it work by destroying your model **after** the end of its removal (Backbone does one last thing after triggering the `remove` event: destroy the collection's reference in the model).

But what's even better, is using directly the `destroy` function on the model, it will remove it from the collection automatically (use `{wait: true}` if needed).

**Edit:**
Finally managed to locate the source of the problem. It's rather simple in fact. To override the model's `url` (calculated with `urlRoot` but that doesn't matter), you can pass `Model#destroy` a `url` option when calling `Backbone.sync` (or something that'll call it).
Now you're thinking "but I don't!". But you do. The listener (`Model#destroy` in your case) is given 3 arguments. `Model#destroy` will take the first one (the model itself) as `options`.
And here's the fail (I think Backbone needs a patch to this): giving an `url` option to `Backbone.sync` is the only time `_.result` in not used to calculate the url. So you find yourself having as url the url property of your model, which is the function you see in your call.

Now, for a quickfix:

```
this.on('remove', this.destroy.bind(this, {}));
```

This will ensure the first argument of your `Model#destroy` call is `{}` (as well as binding the context).

Bear with me a little longer.

Now, if you're still willing to call `Collection#remove` **before** destroying your model, here's a little hack: because (as I stated above) the `remove` event is triggered **before** Backbone makes sure to remove the collection's reference in your model, you don't need the `urlRoot` property in your model. Indeed, the model won't be in the collection anymore, but Backbone will still take the collection's url into account to get the model's url (as the reference is still there).

Comment: Thanks, It works. Also works using of anonymous function as argument  this.on('remove', function () { this.destroy(); });

Comment: Sure do, but longer and unnecessary. Well that's just my opinion :p

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but just going by the code in your question and the [backbone.js documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove), the problem may be that you named your method `remove` and this is getting in the way of the `remove` method in `Backbone.View`.

http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove

**Update**:

It also looks like the output you see in the network inspector is that the definition of the `Backbone.Model.url` function is being appended. Meaning `url` is not being properly called (Maybe the `()` is missing by the caller?). Are you overriding `Backbone.sync` anywhere in your application?

Comment: I changed method name and nothing changed.

Comment: It's not a `()`. Backbone relies heavily on `_.result` for such things.